# Among thioester and ester which has more electrophilic carbonyl carbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, nucleophilic-substitution

In few reactions I’ve seen that nucleophiles preferably attack **thioester’s carbonyl carbon** instead of **ester’s carbonyl carbon**

[image]

According to me, the initiation of reaction is decided by the electrophilicity of the carbonyl compound, in esters O being more electronegative makes c=o more electrophilic, thus attack should have been at ester, but many reactions suggest that attack first occurs at thioester.

What makes thioester’s carbonyl carbon more electrophilic?

Comment: Maybe because the negative charge is more stable on $\ce{S}$ compared to $\ce{O}$.

Comment: Yes maybe that's the correct reason, but the initiation of reaction is decided by the electrophilicity of the carbonyl compound, in esters O being more electronegative makes c=o more electrophilic, thus attack should have been at ester, but many reactions suggest that attack first occurs at thioester.

Comment: Sulfur makes a better leaving group than oxygen.  That makes nucleophilic attack faster at the sulfur-bound site.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yeah this makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Reactivity of thioesters with respect to nucleophilic attack](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27132/16683)

[Why is the thioester bond weaker than a regular ester bond?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/42848/16683)

Let's consider a reaction mechanism like this:

[image: reaction mechanism]

A steady-state analysis will show that the rate of formation of product is

$$r = \frac{k_1k_2[\text{ester}][\text{Nu}]}{k_{-1} + k_2}$$

- $k_1$ for the thioester is larger, because the sulfur 3p lone pair overlaps poorly with the C=O π* orbital (which is formed from 2p orbitals). Recall that esters are less electrophilic than ketones *because* there is an ester oxygen which has a lone pair capable of overlapping with the C=O π*. In this case, since this overlap is diminished, it turns out that thioesters are typically roughly as reactive towards nucleophilic attack as ketones.
- $k_2$ for the thioester is also larger because thiolates are better leaving groups than alkoxides.

Depending on the relative rates of $k_2$ and $k_{-1}$, though, the second point may or may not be relevant. For example if $k_2 \gg k_{-1}$, then the rate equation simplifies to $r \approx k_1[\text{ester}][\text{Nu}]$, in which case the comparison of $k_2$ is no longer useful.

Comment: @ΑντώνιοςΚελεσίδης leaving group ability is quite thoroughly discussed on the internet and you will be able to find more info than I can give you in a comment. Broadly speaking the rule of thumb is the stronger the acid HX the better the leaving group X-.