# Where should we place alpha,beta unsaturated carbonyls in the reactivity order list?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14618/rationalising-the-order-of-reactivity-of-carbonyl-compounds-towards-nucleophiles) question, reasons for this observed trend of reactivity of different types of carbonyl compounds are discussed.

[image]

I would like to know where we can place $\alpha,\beta$ unsaturated carbonyls in this list.

Initially I thought we can place them above acyl chlorides because now we have *2* electrophilic carbons but then I think the reactivity of both of the carbons should also be reduced because of conjugation so they should be placed somewhere in the middle, but where exactly?

Comment: What carbonyls? Ketones?

Comment: Both aldehydes and ketones @Mithoron

Comment: Well, they are already there, as ketones and aldehydes.

Comment: @Mithoron  Presence of adjacent unsaturation *is* going to affect reactivity, isn't it?

Comment: Everything does, but you seem to overestimate it.